# Installing Faiss in a Docker container

Tags: linux, bash, dockerfile, conda, faiss

I'm trying to integrate the Faiss library into a Rasa actions server. The [suggested installation method](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/blob/main/INSTALL.md) for the `faiss-cpu` package is via conda.

I've naively assembled the following Dockerfile to build a custom image which contains both Rasa SDK and FAISS.

```
FROM rasa/rasa-sdk:3.5.1

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements-actions.txt requirements.txt
COPY . /app

USER root

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl bzip2  && \
    curl https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh > /tmp/conda.sh && \
    bash /tmp/conda.sh -b -p /opt/conda && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda update -n base conda && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda install -y -c pytorch faiss-cpu && \
    apt-get remove -y --auto-remove curl bzip2 && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -fr /tmp/conda.sh

ENV PATH="/opt/conda/bin:${PATH}"

USER 1001

EXPOSE 5055

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "-m", "rasa_sdk", "--actions", "actions"]
```

However, the build was unsuccessful. The last few lines of my `docker build` log contain the following:

```
#11 54.72 /bin/bash: line 1: /opt/conda/bin/conda: No such file or directory
------
executor failed running [/bin/bash -o pipefail -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl bzip2 && curl https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh > /tmp/conda.sh && bash /tmp/conda.sh -b -p /opt/conda && /opt/conda/bin/conda update -n base conda && /opt/conda/bin/conda install -y -c pytorch faiss-cpu && apt-get remove -y --auto-remove curl bzip2 && apt-get clean && rm -fr /tmp/conda.sh]: exit code: 127
```

Does the absence of `/opt/conda/bin/conda` mean that conda wasn't installed correctly? Or have I referenced the wrong default directory? Or something else?

I'm also wondering if this is a situation where a multi-stage build would be more appropriate.